# Makefile related

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have a Makefile where the first line is of the type:

```
all:client.so simulator
         LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/shared/lib/client.so ./simulator
```

and the other lines to above follows

Now, I have another program say xyz.c whose executable is called from within simulator using execve().

How can I include the compilation linking etc of xyz.c in the same Makefile or do I have to use another makefile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just make `all` depend on the executable for xyc as well? And then add targets to build that from xyc.c?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a dependency and a rule to build it:

```
simulator: xyz.c
     $CC xyz.c -o yxz
```